# why some jpg images i select from mobile wont detect?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-type

could someone please check what is wrong with this code that some jpg images click from mobile are not getting detected as a jpg?

here is my code

```
if($_FILES["file"]["type"] !='' && !in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"))){
            $error[] = 'We accept only JPG / JPEG image format.';
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Have you checked what type those images have? Do `var_dump($_FILES['file']['type'])` and see what mime type it says.

Comment: i tested the same image on my laptop it is recognizing but when i try uploading from my android phone using firefox browser i get the 'We accept only JPG / JPEG image format.' message.

Comment: I understand. But you need to do some debugging, which is what I suggested in my first comment. We can't possibly know what your phone is sending. Check what `$_FILES['file']['type']` contains when you upload it on mobile. You can probably change the error message to this to make it easier: `'We accept only JPG / JPEG image format. Got: ' . $_FILES['file']['type'];`. Now when you test on your phone, it should say what type it got.

Comment: Thanks let me try the debugging and get back.

Comment: I added max limit to 2mb its showing this error instead of file too large on mobile

Comment: if($_FILES["file"]["size"] !='' && $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2024 ){
      $error[] = 'Selected image size is too large, upload under 10mb.';
  }elseif($_FILES["file"]["type"] !='' && !in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"))){
      $error[] = 'We accept only JPG / JPEG image format.';
  }

Comment: The check: `$_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2024` checks if the file is larger than 2024 _bytes_, which is about 2kb, not 2mb. I also don't have a clue where the size came in to play? We were talking about the type, not size. Please stick to one issue at the time.

Comment: I am sticking to it :) this is what i noticed and sorry my bad its 2097152 2mb, if file is larger than 2mb i get the error message like i said whereas it should show upload under 2mb

Comment: _"I am sticking to it"_ - No you aren't. Your question was about the code not allowing the upload based on the _type_. Now you're talking about the _size_. Those are two different things. You didn't even give any us feedback about debugging the type-issue.